# How To Match UDT T-SQL AND C# CLR Types?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, clr, sqlclr

Unsure if this question makes sense but I'm new to CLR/UDT and just finished following through this example here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration/database-objects/getting-started-with-clr-integration?view=sql-server-2017

What I want to achieve right now is pretty similar. I've tried adding in a string parameter without fail, but when adding a C# object is where the issue begins.

This is my C# Main:

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
public static void HelloName(Person person, [param: SqlFacet(MaxSize=-1)]out string result)
{
    SqlContext.Pipe.Send("Hello world!" + Environment.NewLine);
    result = "Hello, " + person.firstName + " " + person.lastName;
}
```

And this is the C# Person class:

```
    public class Person
    {
        public string firstName;
        public string lastName;
        public Person(string firstName, string lastName)
        {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }
    }
```

I'm able to successfully create the assembly, but it's the procedure where I get stuck. I want to do something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE helloname
(
    @person (@firstname nchar(300), @lastname nchar(300))
    @result nchar(300) OUTPUT
 )
AS EXTERNAL NAME helloworld.HelloWorldProc.HelloName
```

But after some research apparently the best way to go about objects is through UDTs. I have followed another example and created both a Person table and a PersonType as below in T-SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE Person  
(  
    FirstName nvarchar(50),  
    LastName nvarchar(50)  
)  
Go  

CREATE TYPE PersonType AS TABLE  
(  
    FirstName nvarchar(50),  
    LastName nvarchar(50)  
)  
Go
```

The error occurs here:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE helloname
(
    @personType PersonType,
    @result nchar(300) OUTPUT
)
AS EXTERNAL NAME helloworld.HelloWorldProc.HelloName
```

On attempted execution it says "CREATE PROCEDURE for "helloname" failed because T-SQL and CLR types for parameter "@personType" do not match."

How do I get "PersonType" to equal the C# Class "Person" for this to work properly? Let me know if I'm going about this the completely wrong way/if there's a simpler solution. Ideally I will be passing in a List with multiple variable types inside Person. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have misunderstood the concept of User-Defined Types. These are not the same thing as User-Defined Data Types (mapping a random name to an actual T-SQL datatype) or User-Defined Table Types (predefined table schemas used for creating table variables, typically used as Table-Valued Parameters).

Try this for a better intro: [CLR User-Defined Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-types/clr-user-defined-types)

> Let me know if I'm going about this the completely wrong way/if there's a simpler solution. Ideally I will be passing in a List with multiple variable types inside Person.

If the Stored Procedure was going to be a T-SQL stored proc, then the best way to do this would be to use a User-Defined Table Type / TVP (i.e. `CREATE TYPE PersonType AS TABLE...`). But since SQLCLR does not accept TVP's, you can do either:

- construct the list of complex "objects" as an XML document, which is easily parsed in .NET. Use `SqlXml` as the .NET input parameter type.
- create a Local Temporary Table (i.e. starting with a single `#`), populate it, and then read from it in the SQLCLR stored procedure using `Context Connection = true` as the connection string. I'm not sure under what conditions this option would be better / easier than simply passing in an XML document, but it is still an option.

Other notes:

1. You don't need the `param:` part of the `SqlFacet` attribute.
2. Use `SqlString` as the incoming datatype instead of `string`. Get the .NET string via `ParamName.Value` property. Check if `NULL` via `ParamName.IsNull` property.
3. Parameters cannot be expressed as combinations of parameters. Meaning, `@person (@firstname nchar(300), @lastname nchar(300))` is not valid syntax under any condition.

For more info on working with SQLCLR in general, please visit: [SQLCLR Info](https://SQLCLR.org/)